# Ruby Cucumber: Pausing the Suite for demos and debugging, with the ability to resume

Tags: ruby, cucumber

As a software tester, I want to be able to pause test execution with cucumber at any stage during test execution, in order to debug failing tests and show features to clients during demos in more detail.

```
Scenario: Pause suite mid demo, then resume
 Given I am in a meeting to show off a new feature our team has developed
 And a client asks us a question about the page we are currently on
 When I press the 'p' key in the terminal
 Then I should have enough time to answer the question in detail to the client
 And I should be able to resume test execution by pressing the 'enter' key in the terminal

Scenario: Pause suite at a known point for debugging
 Given there is a failed test
 When I add the "pause" method to the step definition
 Then the test should pause execution until pressing the 'enter' key in the terminal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions here work on Windows, and so should work on most other operating systems.

```
# Checks for a pause command in the command line and if it has been pressed, will pause
def paused?
    if STDIN.ready?
      last_input = STDIN.gets
      while last_input == 'p'
        sleep 1
      end
    end
end

# Pauses for debugging, will continue when enter is pressed
def pause
  print 'p'
  last_input = STDIN.gets
  while last_input == 'p'
    sleep 1
  end
end
```

The first, when placed once at the start of each step definition, gives the ability to pause straight after a step is completed by pressing 'p' in the terminal.

Alternatively, creating an abstraction library may produce better results, as the `paused?` method can be used throughout this to pause at other points during execution than the beginning of a new step. This will resume when any standard key other than 'p' is pressed, but I would recommend a new line.

The second, will simply pause the test until any key is pressed, at which point, execution can resume - ideal for debugging.

Happy Pausing!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [AfterStep hook](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#tagged-hooks)

```
AfterStep('@pauseable') do
  answer = 'n'
  begin
    Timeout.timeout 1 do # wait for a second for user to press 'p'
      answer = STDIN.getch
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error  # answer is 'n' when no key is pressed during 1 second
  end

  STDIN.getch if answer == 'p' # wait until user presses any key
end
```

Now you can tag your feature as `@pauseable`. Run it and press `p` to pause it. Then press any key to continue

Comment: This is a great addition for those who want to pause after a step has finished, and I would definitely recommend using this method if pausing during step execution isn’t necessary.